# SQL with two weightings where one weighting is joined from another table

Tags: sql

I have a SQL table with the following format:

| Image_Key | Continent | Country | Date_Used |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| poems | Europe | France | 2023-07-15 |
| horse | Asia | China | 2023-07-14 |
| monument | Europe | France | 2023-07-13 |
| plane | Europe | Germany | 2023-07-12 |
| horse | Asia | China | 2010-04-10 |
| tide | Oceania | Australia | 2000-02-02 |

Each day I'm trying to select an random image key that:

1. hasn't been used in the past 6 months

```
SELECT
    `Image_Key`
FROM
    table1
WHERE
    `Date_Used` < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 182 DAY
```

2. is from a country not used in the past seven days

```
SELECT
    `Image_Key`
FROM
    table1
WHERE
    `Date_Used` < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 182 DAY 
AND 'Country' NOT IN(
    SELECT
        Country
    FROM
        table1
    WHERE
        'Date_Used' > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 7 DAY
)
```

3. has a weighting towards choosing an image key that was used the least recent

```
SELECT
    `Image_Key`,
    - LOG(RAND()) / DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, `Date_Used`) AS priority
FROM
    table1
WHERE
    `Date_Used` < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 182 DAY 
 AND 'Country' NOT IN(
    SELECT
        Country
    FROM
        table1
    WHERE
        'Date_Used' > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 7 DAY
)
ORDER BY
    priority
LIMIT 1
```

4. has a weighting against choosing an image key based on the continent count in the last 14 days.

I have come up with the following to get the continent count in the last 14 days:

```
(
    SELECT
        continent,
        COUNT(*)
    FROM
        (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            *
        FROM
            table1
        WHERE
            `Date_Used` BETWEEN(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 14 DAY) AND(CURRENT_DATE)
    ) AS total_count
GROUP BY
    Continent
)
```

However I'm not sure how to join these results into the following, and weighting a high continent count against it being chosen.

I think the desired code would look something like this, however I'm not sure how to tie in the continent count to the second weighting

```
SELECT
    `Image_Key`,
    - LOG(RAND()) / DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, `Date_Used`) AS Date_priority,
    - LOG(RAND()) / (continent_count) AS Continent_priority
FROM
    table1
WHERE
    `Date_Used` < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 168 DAY 
    AND 'Country' NOT IN (SELECT Country
                          FROM table1
                          WHERE 'Date_Used' > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
ORDER BY
    `Date_priority` ASC,
    `Continent_priority` DESC
```

Comment: What is your expected result based on your table rows?

Comment: My expected result is that the selection would favour the Image_Key 'tide' as it was used the least recently and is from a continent with a low count in the last 14 days

Comment: Why are you calling `RAND`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have omitted `RAND` because I don't know why a random weight would be useful but you can introduce it if you want.

Your weights need to be selected in with the rest of your columns. Your 6-month predicate (which should be expressed in months and not days) can be a simple `where`. Your country-week predicate should be expressed as a `not exists`.

It's important that, for clarity, you re-frame the `priority` as either a cost or a merit value. I show it as a cost.

From the results of this query, you would probably want to order by increasing cost sum and choose the top *n*.

```sql
create table table1(
    Image_Key text not null,
    Continent text not null,
    Country text not null,
    Date_Used date not null
);

insert into table1(Image_Key, Continent, Country, Date_Used) values
    ('poems',    'Europe',  'France',    '2023-07-15'),
    ('horse',    'Asia',    'China',     '2023-07-14'),
    ('monument', 'Europe',  'France',    '2023-07-13'),
    ('plane',    'Europe',  'Germany',   '2023-07-12'),
    ('horse',    'Asia',    'China',     '2010-04-10'),
    ('tide',     'Oceania', 'Australia', '2000-02-02');

select all_images.*,
    coalesce(recent_continents.freq, 0) as recent_continent_cost,
    -log(current_date - date_used) as age_cost
from table1 as all_images
left join (
    select Continent, count(*) as freq
    from table1
    where Date_Used >= current_date - interval '14' day
    group by Continent
) recent_continents on recent_continents.Continent = all_images.Continent
where Date_Used < current_date - interval '6' month
    and not exists(
        select 1
        from table1
        where Country = all_images.Country
            and Date_Used >= current_date - interval '7' day
    )
;
```